# How can I distinguish component Id between different xml file in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Now, I'm develop android application.
and i want to distinguish component Id between different xml file!
For example, mycode is,

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this.getIntent());
        String s=intent.getStringExtra("text");
        viewTest=new ViewTest();
        if(s.equals("a"))
            setContentView(R.layout.a);
        else
            setContentView(R.layout.b);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonA:
                  Log.d("ButtonA","ButtonA!!");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

and a.xml

> ```
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="New Button"
>     android:id="@+id/buttonA" /> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

and b.xml

> ```
> <Button
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="New Button"
>     android:id="@+id/buttonA" /> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

a.xml and b.xml are have Button, and Id's are same(`R.id.buttonA`)
so how can I distinguish component Id?

if I `setContentView(R.layout.a);`, when Clicked Button `Log.d("ButtonA","ButtonA!!");`is execute,
but If i`setContentView(R.layout.b)`, when Clicked Button, 
`Log.d("ButtonA","ButtonA!!");`is not execute!
how can I add distinguish code?

Comment: Add some log output to `onCick` to see what button ID you are getting.

Comment: I getting `R.id.buttonA` Id is 2131492922 and `R.layout.a` Id is 2130968576, `R.layout.b` id is 2130968604

Comment: Sorry i edit my mistake!  and get Same ButtonA Id  in a.xml, b.xml(Smae Id 2131492922 )

Answer (score 0):

I just checked with the exact same scenario as above and it works. I think the problem is with the way you have set the `onClickListener`. It should be

```
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and not

```
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

How the xml work is, whenever you set the content using `setContentView();` whichever layout is specified in the `R.layout.your_file` file will be loaded. And after that whenever you do `findViewById(R.id.whatever)` it will try to look for that particular id in that particular layout file. In your case since you have `buttonA` id in both your xml files you don't have to worry.

Also, suppose you had `buttonA` id in one file and `buttonB` in the other, then the line

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
```

would return you `null`, since it would not be able to find the `buttonB` in `R.layout.A`.

Comment: I edit my mistake,
and you say means, i will change Id in xml?
just, I want how can I distinguished layout!(or xml!)

Comment: Your code should work just fine. `Log.d("ButtonA","ButtonA!!");` should be printed both the times, whether `a.xml` or `b.xml` is loaded.

Comment: Can you paste your entire a.xml and b.xml so that we can verify.

Comment: yes! my code is execute a.xml, and b.xml .   but my question is if opened a.xml, execute `Log.d("ButtonA","ButtonA!!")`! but if opened b.xml, not execute `Log.d("ButtonA","ButtonA!!")`!